# Graphics lag on Ubuntu 11.10 x64 with Nvidia 9400 GT on Admin user

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics, 64-bit, partial-upgrade

Ubuntu 11.10 x64
Kernel 3.0.0-14-generic
Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 2.93 GHz
2 GB Kingston DDR3
NVidia 9400 GT, driver 280.13

My admin account has a graphics problem. It glitches and fractures. But the strange thing, it only happen in my main account. In another account, the graphics performances is flawless. It happened after I've run partial upgrade (I don't know why, it ask for partial upgrade even after I restarted my box) and uninstalling KeepassX.

I've made mistake when I uninstall KeepassX. I'm forgot to close the App. After I've uninstalled KeepassX, The app still running. I've tried to close the app but it started to lack. My ubuntu performance started decreasing. Then I restart my computer. After logon screen, the graphics started to lag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: When using older kernel, it runs normal. Is it kernel bug?

Comment: +1 I'm also experiencing serious lag after a recent update.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards